# Toggle A QAction To Set QStackedWidget's Current Widget

Tags: qt, qt5

So what I am trying to do is when I press the showMenu (QAction), the container (QStackedWidget) changes the current widget to menuWidget AND when I press it again it hides.

Ok so I have managed to get this code:

```
connect(showMenu, SIGNAL(triggered()), map, SLOT(map()));
map->setMapping(menuWidget, container);
Object::connect(map, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget *)), container, SLOT(setCurrentWidget(QWidget *)));
```

also if I run:

```
container->setCurrentWidget(menuWidget);
```

directly, it works fine, so I have not messed up in that way.

Comment: Your `setMapping` call looks strange. It seems like you should pass `showMenu` and `menuWidget` to it: `map->setMapping(showMenu, menuWidget);`

Comment: @thuga that worked, thanks so much! You have any idea how I can simple change it back when clicking the showMenu action again?

Comment: I'd recommend making a slot in your class, like `MyClass::menuToggled(bool checked)`. Then connect [`QAction::toggled(bool checked)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#checked-prop) signal to this slot. Then in that slot check if `checked` is true or not and hide/show your `menuWidget` based on that.

Comment: `connect(showMenu, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(menuToggled(bool)));`
`void MainWindow::menuToggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        container->setCurrentWidget(menuWidget);
    }
}`
Now it does nothing :( @thuga

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought you were operating on a checkable `QAction` object. You can set it to checkable with [`QAction::setCheckable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#checkable-prop). Or if you don't want to have a checkable action, use a `bool` member variable that you toggle in the `menuToggled` slot (you can remove the `bool checked` parameter from the slot) .

Comment: Try `container->setCurrentWidget(checked ? menuWidget : nullptr);`

Comment: @thuga now I have this: http://pastebin.com/CcRStL0B . I think it is because I'm looping it wrong?

RobbieE returns this: QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget: widget 0x0 not contained in stack

Comment: @thuga can you provide an example please, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Yeah, the problem in your code snippet is that you're using a local `bool` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a slot in your class where you show/hide `menuWidget`.

If you are using a checkable `QAction` object, then you can use [`QAction::toggled(bool checked)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#checked-prop) signal, and use the `checked` variable to determine if you should show or hide your widget.

If you're not using a checkable `QAction` object, then you should create a class member variable of type `bool` that you toggle in your slot:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
private:
    bool toggleStatus; // set this to false in your constructor
    ...
};
```

```
void MainWindow::menuToggled()
{
    toggleStatus = !toggleStatus;
    if(toggleStatus)
    {
        container->setCurrentWidget(menuWidget);
    }
    else
    {
        container->setCurrentWidget(mdiContainer);
    }
}
```